# Jenkins warnings publisher failing while build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a a checkstyle stage that creates a flake8 report and uses the warnings publisher. When I run the build I get the below error.

I have installed the "static analysis collector plugin" as well.

```
withEnv(["VIR_ENV=$env.WORKSPACE/venv"]){
            stage ('Check_style') {
                 sh """
                    #. venv/bin/activate
                    export PATH=${VIRENV}/bin:${PATH}
                    echo $PATH
                    make flake8 | tee test-report/flake8.log || true
                """
                step([$class: 'WarningsPublisher',
                  parserConfigurations: [[
                    parserName: 'Pep8',
                    pattern: 'report/flake8.log'
                  ]],
                  unstableTotalAll: '0',
                  usePreviousBuildAsReference: true
                ])
            }
        }
```

Error:-

```
Build failed with Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {delegate={$class=WarningsPublisher, parserConfigurations=[{parserName=Pep8, pattern=report/flake8.log}], unstableTotalAll=0, usePreviousBuildAsReference=true}} for CoreStep(delegate:
```